# Column Types when reading into DataTable

Tags: c#, npgsql

After reading the whole content into a DataTable via Load, the type of all columns of the `Rows.ItemArray` are always "object". Despite at runtime, the correct types should be known by the reader.
I need a DataTable presentation for some reasons.

```
using (var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, conn)) 
{
    var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    int fieldCount = reader.FieldCount;
    workTable = new DataTable(DateTime.Now.ToString());
    workTable.Load(reader);
    return workTable;
}
```

---

It's because I need a complete data presentation of my query in memory. So that requirements forces me to define as follows:

```
public IDictionary Pair(string key1, string key2)
{
    var r = from DataRow r1 in workTable.Rows
            from DataRow r2 in workTable.Rows
            select new { rk1 = r1[key1], rk2 = r2[key2] };

    Dictionary<Object, Object> result = r.ToDictionary(x => x.rk1, x => x.rk2);

    return result;
}
```

It works, but I'm new to c# and I think maybe there's some possibility to make it more precisely regarding the data types.

Comment: That's because ItemArray is an array of objects. Your DataTable Columns collection should contain the exact datatype for each column. You don't need the ItemArray here.

Comment: See my edits above.

Comment: Why do you need a DataTable? Why can't you use a strongly typed object?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to identify the datatype of the columns of a DataTable. You can access the DataTable.Columns collection. as an example.

if you have the following table structure.

```
CREATE TABLE table01 (
  id      int NOT NULL,
  field1  varchar(30),
  field2  timestamp);
```

you can execute the following snippet

```
string sql = "Select * from table01";
using (var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(cs))
{
    conn.Open();
    using (var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, conn))
    {
        var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        int fieldCount = reader.FieldCount;
        var workTable = new DataTable(DateTime.Now.ToString());
        workTable.Load(reader);

        for (int i = 0; i < workTable.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"field: {workTable.Columns[i].ColumnName} is of type {workTable.Columns[i].DataType.ToString()}");

        }

    }
}
```

and the following will be outputted.

```
field: id is of type System.Int32
field: field1 is of type System.String
field: field2 is of type System.DateTime
```

-HTH